# Jquery: get xml from the web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Trying to get xml from the web service:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://77.65.139.254:10000/_layouts/SPWebService/SPService.asmx/GetFileContentByUrl',
                data: { fileUrl: 'Accounts/8b077249-98bb-e011-926f-00155d000e46/EVTemplates/FEFCO0200/FEFCO%200203_3D.JPG' },                
                dataType: 'text/xml',
                success: function (html) {
                    alert('yes');
                }
            });
```

the result is: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{1f083902-dc6e-4e0b-a18e-4aa1ab99ff56} Line Number 1, Column 1:

my request looks like:

```
Host    77.65.139.254:10000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Origin  null
```

When I insert the link in the browser - it works ok - returns xml.
the request (valid) looks like:

```
GET /_layouts/SPWebService/SPService.asmx/GetFileContentByUrl?fileUrl=Accounts/8b077249-98bb-e011-926f-00155d000e46/EVTemplates/FEFCO0200/FEFCO%200203_3D.JPG HTTP/1.1
Host: 77.65.139.254:10000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
```

What is wrong with my jquery get?

Comment: Is the script in the same domain of the XML?

Comment: You can't use AJAX calls to fetch data from different domain

Comment: Any workaround? Why it returns xml in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to proxy the XML request. Make the Cross-domain from backend and echo it locally.

This article might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx or this: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=409